# figuring out which git stash is applied

Tags: git, diff, git-stash

I had created a bunch of stashes (each with a message btw, using 'git stash save "my message" ') and then applied one of those stashes (using 'git stash apply stash@{n}') which was NOT the most recent stash.

Now few days later, I can't remember which one I had applied. I ran a bunch of long-running tests which passed after applying the stash so it is important for me to know the answer.

To figure out which stash I may have applied, I looked thru the documentation and the SO questions but didn't find a clue. The only idea that comes to my mind is doing

```
git diff > mydiff.txt
```

and then comparing mydiff.txt with each of the patch files obtained for the stashes. That is, obtain the patch for say the second stash:

```
git show -p stash@{1} > 1.txt
```

and compare mydiff.txt against 1.txt:

```
diff mydiff.txt 1.txt
```

to figure out if stash@{1} was the one I applied. This is a bit tedious especially in the scenario where changes were made after applying the stash.
Is there a better/"less-brute-force" way to find out which stash was actually applied? Would greatly appreciate any pointers from people who know better.

Comment: I'm afraid there is only the brute-force way … Applying a stash will only apply its changes, not record anywhere that the stash has been applied

Answer (score 1):

If you ran the stash from terminal, you can check for the bash history for which commands you've run recently - a simple

```
history | grep "git stash apply"
```

should give you the most recent git stash applied.

---

If that is not an option - brute force is the only way to go.

Though, you could ask yourself if the relevant stash would be more similar to the current diff then any other stash in your git history (i.e., you don't have any trivial stashes). If that is the case, you can smarten your approach by writing a simple script that compares each of your stash to the current diff, and gives you the count of number of lines that differ between the stashed version and current diff - the lower the number of differing lines the better:

```
git stash list | wc -l # find number of stashes to look through
git diff > current_diff.txt
# while loop for the count in stash list
git show -p stash@{iter} > iter.txt
diff iter.txt current_diff.txt | wc -l > iter_diff.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for idea about examining the history and for scripting the num-lines that diff'ed.  Unfortunately in my case the two stashes have similar number of differing lines.  But good idea, all the same.